# ToolTip Html Helper

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to build an HTML helper that will work like the `HTML.ForLabel` helper but will set the title attribute to the value of description in the `[Display]` annotation.  I have the tooltip part working but I can't get the `htmlAttributes` to work.

Here is my code for the helper

```
public static class LabelWithTooltip
{

    public static MvcHtmlString Tooltip<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression, IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes)
    {
        var metaData = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, helper.ViewData);

        string htmlFieldName = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression);

        string labelText = metaData.DisplayName ?? metaData.PropertyName ?? htmlFieldName.Split('.').Last();

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(labelText))
        {
            return MvcHtmlString.Empty;
        }

        var label = new TagBuilder("label");

        label.Attributes.Add("for", helper.ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldId(htmlFieldName));

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(metaData.Description))
        {
            label.Attributes.Add("title", metaData.Description);
            label.MergeAttributes(htmlAttributes);
        }

        label.SetInnerText(labelText);
        return MvcHtmlString.Create(label.ToString());
    }
}
```

And here is the line to invoke it in the view

```
@Html.Tooltip(model => model.Guid, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
```

It is not taking the values I am passing for the `htmlAttributes`

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you get any errors, please attach.. Also isn’t Tooltip method expects 3 parameters, but you’re passing 2?

Comment: @numbtongue this is an extension method with 2 parameters.

Comment: Assuming you don't have any reported errors, have you tried to run the debugger to the `label.MergeAttributes(htmlAttributes)` line?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because `htmlAttributes` is an anonymous object, and so it needs to be passed as an `object`, not a dictionary. After that, you can use `HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes()` to give you back the dictionary you need to merge with the `TagBuilder`.

Like this:

```
public static MvcHtmlString Tooltip<TModel, TValue>(
    this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, 
    Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression, 
    object htmlAttributes) // Note the signature change.
{
    // ... snip

    var attributes = HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(htmlAttributes);
    label.MergeAttributes(attributes);

    // ... snip
}
```

This will correctly merge the `htmlAttributes` with the label.